# How to show bar chart labels clearly using ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

In my Angular project, I want to use ChartJS to draw a barchart. The number of data for this chart are random and variable. It may be very large sometimes.

When the number is large, the labels are overlap each other as:  [image]

I want to know how to automatically adjust the space and show the label correctly?

Source code is: 
Javascript:

```
  // Bar chart mock data
  barChartOptions:any = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
  responsive: true
  };
  barChartLabels:string[] = ['2018-10-02 15:26:41', ...];
  barChartType:string = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartLegend:boolean = true;
  barChartData:any[] = [{data: data, label: 'Kilometre per Litre'}];
```

html

```
<div style="display: block">
   <canvas baseChart id="mpgChart"
       [datasets]="barChartData"
       [labels]="barChartLabels"
       [options]="barChartOptions"
       [legend]="barChartLegend"
       [chartType]="barChartType"
       (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
       (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```

scss

```
 #mpgChart{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `autoSkip: true`. This is how you would do it in normal Chart.JS, not sure how you can do it in Angular2 Chart.js

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      autoSkip: true
    }
  }]
}
```

You can also add `minRotation: 30`, to rotate the text to increase the text readability

** Edit **

```
  barChartOptions:any = {
      scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
       scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: true
          }
         }]
      },
      responsive: true
  };
```